# Tomcat 7.0.43 "INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header"

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I use Tomcat 7.0.43 with a websocket application. My app works fine in Tomcat 7.0.42 but with 43 I get the following output when I try to access my server on websockets:

```
Sep 16, 2013 3:08:34 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

My browser console shows the following:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.testapp.com/socket/notification/848df2e62fcf93e1b3?X-Atmosphere-tracking-i…Date=0&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Unrecognized frame opcode: 5
```

Here is the access log for that request:

```
"GET /socket/notification/848df2e62fcf93e1b3?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.2-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true HTTP/1.1"
```

**What has changed in Tomcat 7.0.43? What do I have to change?**

Comment: Can you show the HTTP headers you are sending?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis see my access log. Does this help you?

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583338/unrecognized-frame-opcode-5-and-web-socket-closes

Comment: @fatman Why should Tomcat 7.0.43 not support the websocket I use with Tomcat 7.0.42? It does not make any sense?

Comment: you are getting `failed: Unrecognized frame opcode: 5` so obviously the problem is in that area. I'm not familiar with the protocol but just thought it might give you a pointer (maybe you set a version header?).

Comment: @fatman but why does this change from version 42 to 43?

Comment: @confile did you manage to find any solution? I am facing same issue

Comment: @SorryBoss no not yet. If you find a solution please post it. I know that in Tomcat 7.0.43 the specification for web sockets have changed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you have this listener:

```
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
```

on your server.xml, remove it and try.
You can not use a keystore if you are using the APR connector

Answer (score 23):

Check, if you are not accidentally requesting HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP.

I have overlooked that I was requesting `https://localhost:...` instead of `http://localhost:...` and it resulted to this weird message..

Comment: Great. Thanks, this was my problem.

Comment: My problem too; especially when I looked at localhost_access_log and everything after the IP address and date was hex data!

Answer (score 22):

For me, the problem was passing in a larger than normally expected HTTP header. I resolved it by setting maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576" attribute on the Connector node in server.xml.

Answer (score 21):

If there are too many cookies cached, it breaks the server (the size of a request header is too big!).  Clearing the cookies can fix this issue as well.

Comment: i had the problem with httpclient, i used `method.addHeader` instead of `method.setHeader`

Comment: i just have one header attached and that is content type and still i am getting the same error . can u advice ?

Comment: @user641887 then probably your issue is not from the size of request header

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue, I was sending a POST request (using RESTClient plugin for Firefox) with data in the request body and was receiving the same message.

In my case this happened because I was trying to use HTTPS protocol in a local tomcat instance where HTTPS was not configured.

Comment: yup, same thing in my case it was typo someone tried https://localhost:8080

Comment: Even in my case this is the issue, one of the developer hitting from postman with https.

Answer (score 5):

My problem occurs when I try to open **https**. I don't use SSL.

It's Tomcat [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60581).

Today *12/02/2017* newest official version from Debian repositories is **Tomcat 8.0.14**

Solution is to download from official site and install newest package of **Tomcat 8, 8.5, 9** or upgrade to newest version(**8.5.x**) from jessie-backports

#### Debian 8

Add to */etc/apt/sources.list*

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Then update and install Tomcat from jessie-backports

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install tomcat8
```

Comment: bug report for debian and tomcat 8.0.14 environment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851304

Answer (score 3):

I tried all of the above, nothing worked for me.
Then I changed tomcat port numbers both HTTP/1.1 and Tomcat admin port and it got solved.

I see other solutions above worked for the people but it is worth to try this one if any of the above doesn't work.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

In our case it turned out that the error happened because we have a custom `filter` in our application which does `HttpServletResponse sendRedirect()` to other url.

For some reason, the redirection is not closing the `keep-alive` status of the connection, hence the timeout exception.

We checked with [Tomcat Docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) and when we disabled the `maxKeepAliveRequests` by setting it's value to `1` and the error stopped showing up.

For now we do not have the actual solution to the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when working on a **Java Project** in **Debian 10** with **Tomcat** as the application server.

The issue was that the application already had **https** defined as it's default protocol while I was using **http** to call the application in the browser. So when I try running the application I get this error in my log file:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

I however tried using the **https** protocol in the browser but it didn't connect throwing the error:

**Here's how I solved it**:

You need a certificate to setup the **https** protocol for the application. I first had to create a **keystore** file for the application, more like a self-signed certificate for the **https** protocol:

```
sudo keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore /usr/share/tomcat.keystore
```

**Note**: You need to have Java installed on the server to be able to do this. Java can be installed using `sudo apt install default-jdk`.

Next, I added a **https** Tomcat server connector for the application in the Tomcat server configuration file (`/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml`):

```
sudo nano /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

Add the following to the configuration of the application. Notice that the **keystore** file location and password are specified. Also a port for the **https** protocol is defined, which is different from the port for the **http** protocol:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
           secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat.keystore"
           keystorePass="my-password"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           compression="force"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
```

So the full server configuration for the application looked liked this in the **Tomcat** server configuration file (`/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml`):

```
<Service name="my-application">
  <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
             port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
             secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
             keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat.keystore"
             keystorePass="my-password"
             clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
             URIEncoding="UTF-8"
             compression="force"
             compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>

  <Connector port="8009" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             redirectPort="8443" />

  <Engine name="my-application" defaultHost="localhost">
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
          unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
             prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
             pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

This time when I tried accessing the application from the browser using:

```
https://my-server-ip-address:https-port
```

In my case it was:

```
https:35.123.45.6:8443
```

it worked fine. Although, I had to accept a warning which added a security exception for the website since the certificate used is a self-signed one.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to upgrade your tomcat,
Add this line in your `catalina.properties`

```
tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}
```

It works for me
http://www.zhoulujun.cn/zhoulujun/html/java/tomcat/2018_0508_8109.html