# Why do I get "Error parsing HTTP request header" when POSTing a JSON string?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I am trying to send a `POST` request from browser to my server(local host). My request URL is :

```
 http://localhost:8080/myPath/myServlet?requestData={  .......//Json String......};
```

`requestData` is a json String (I am using GSON for the purpose.) Everything is working fine until the data in the json string exceeds a particular limit. Say, I am sending array of objects in the json string. If the number of objects in the list exceed `67` then I get following error :

```
 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
 INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

Why is this so? I am totally confused. Why does this happen and what needs to be done to fix this?
I want to understand the reason behind this, for I don't understand that after particular number of objects it suddenly stops working and I get this error in my console.

Comment: This seems to be a GET instead POST ...

Comment: It seems that you are passing the json string as a `GET` parameter, not `POST`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: I agree that this might be a duplicate question , Is there any solution ?

Comment: You'll get this error message if you are exceeding url length in get requests aswell

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819180/tomcat-7-0-43-info-error-parsing-http-request-header

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, I was sending a POST request (using RESTClient plugin for Firefox) with data in the request body and was receiving the same message.

In my case this happened because I was trying to use HTTPS protocol in a local tomcat instance where HTTPS was not configured.

Comment: I'm setting up a new tomcat server, and I've somehow configured port 8443 as HTTP (not HTTPS) (not realizing that I did this), so normal requests such as (https://localhost:8443) which normally go to the Manager GUI (on a new instance failed with this error).  I was missing the `SSLEnabled="true"` property on the `<Connector>` element.
Basically the browser is negotiating an SSL/HTTPS connection and the server is only talking HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using POST incorrectly. Although you are using POST you are sending JSON as a request parameter that is the GET style. When using POST you should send content as a request *body*. In this case no reasonable size limitation exist.

Comment: Please take a look on this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: How can I send it from the browser?

Comment: You can write HTML page with `form` tag, define its `method=POST` and configure `action`  to your URL, create text area field, then write your JSON there and press button `submit`.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for not answering questions seriously before.

1.Maybe it caused by special characters.You can get details from this url。https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60594

solve it by：

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))
```

or change your tomcat version to 7.0.67 or lower.
According to developers's opinion, tomcat developers in the following versions set the option to allow `|，{，}`.
Get detail http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Other

The new environment variable will be included in:
- trunk for 9.0.0.M18 onwards

- 8.5.x for 8.5.12 onwards
- 8.0.x for 8.0.42 onwards
- 7.0.x for 7.0.76 onwards2.

Another reason maybe that Request header is too large.You can solve this by modifying the `server.xml`.

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" 
    minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false"
    redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" 
    disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Hope it works for you！

Comment: Try adding example while answering the question to make it more helpful for the person asking.

Comment: Sorry.I've added details of what I know.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was caused by security issues, i used csfr for authentication, and all my post forms should have input with _csrf

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem of parsing the headers can be caused by numerous reasons.

In my case it was due to the fact that the following XML was passed:

```
<soapenv:Header/>
```

The empty header element was generated by SoapUI.
After the removal of the  `<soapenv:Header/>` from the XML of the WS then everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by passing an additional header

**connection: close**, along with the request.

Could you please try and let me know if this works for you.