# WSO2 API Manager : Request Header too Large

Tags: http, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API Manager that sends as-is Http headers to backend. However, when client sends a SAML Response XML to API Manager, Request Header too large error is thrown. Attached Screen shot.

Where can we change the configuration, so as to allow large headers. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the appropriate vlaue to **maxHttpHeaderSize** property in

```
<HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
```

Comment: did you restart the server ?

Comment: how do you send SAML Response XML to API Manager through, Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504212/error-parsing-http-request-header

Comment: may be the value given for  maxHttpHeaderSize is smaller than the saml payload size

Comment: Jenananthan,I am sending the SAML Response XML to API Manager in http headers. When I split the XML and send, it is working perfect. Now, I understand about the payload size you were mentioning. The entire SAML response size is not more than 7KB and I increased the maxHttpHeaderSize to something way bigger than above value. Did a restart of the API M too. But luck is far from near, it seems :)

Comment: Jenananthan,I did small trick while sending from Consumer to Backend via API. I converted the SAML string to Blob and sent to backend. Now, API Manager is NOT COMPLAINING. Looks like API Manager is doing / parsing the XML and not able to understand it. Will keep you posted on that if any thing else comes up.

Comment: @All, instead of sending in HttpHeaders, try sending in body, as suggested by Uvindra Dias Jayasinha (Jira https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5238). Working like charm. Need not do anything on API Manager.