# Error building project with maven

Tags: spring, maven, github

I am building a [project](https://github.com/nihar00/spcm) from github. I have configure this project for my database. After `maven clean install` I get this error:

> `INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
>    Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
>   Jun 04, 2015 5:14:17 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process`

What do I need to do to address that error?

Comment: This is a  server problem, which server are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 and my SQL server 5.6.

Comment: May be this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20144681/1702242

Comment: @pmverma its not this problem. I have checked it before.

Comment: You should better replace a new tomcat, and try to run from command line to see if the problem is with Eclipse or the project itself.

Comment: cmd line didnt help.