# Tomcat 8.0.28 "Error parsing HTTP request header"

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

i am using grails 3.0.9

and this plugin

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6'
compile "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7"
```

i am using [this](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder) plugin to access other server..

this is my code..

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'https://abc.yesido.web.id' )

            http.request(GET,TEXT) { req ->
                uri.path = '/test.php' // overrides any path in the default URL
                uri.query = [ u: test, p: 123, d: destinationNo, m: messages ]

                response.success = { resp, reader ->
                    assert resp.status == 200                   
                    System.out << reader 
                    loggResponse(resp, reader, refNo)
                }
                response.'404' = { resp ->
                    println 'Not found'
                }
            }
```

this code run well ...
but after i leave it a few hours, my tomcat already stop..
this is `catalina.out` message log..

```
23-Mar-2016 16:03:01.515 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

i dont know why my tomcat stoped..

i mnot using websocket or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819180/tomcat-7-0-43-info-error-parsing-http-request-header) issue..

anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hey Akiong I very much doubt any one will be able to give you any specific answer. I suspect the websocket issues you were facing a few months back also relate to this issue. I would say having worked in IT for all these years that is is always stepping back and thinking things from a more simplistic example. You are saying when you load a car with some weight it stops working. I say unload the car i.e. load a default tomcat no app and let that run - does that also fall over after a few hourse?

Comment: my error is not about that. because its different tomcat with my project which using websocket... :D

Comment: my tomcat stopped work because my VPs only have 1 GB Ram and i am using xms = 1024m.